# How to limit maximum upload bandwidth for Windows 10 update in percentage via GPO?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, group-policy, bandwidth, windows-10-v1709

10 days ago I downloaded most recent ADMX Win 10 templates for GPO and successfully set `Maximum Download Bandwidth (percentage)` for affected computers, but I am unable to find an equivalent for **limiting the upload in percentage** - this GPO is just not there. There is only the `Max Upload Bandwidth (in KB/s)` option.

On a client machine with Fall Creators update (latest Win10 "1709" version), I can see this option, but it is not available in the GPO :/

Am I doing something wrong? I've searched the Internet, but no luck so far... Thanks

Comment: What makes you believe there is a equivalent group policy for upload?

Comment: well, usually, when there is some options branch available via GPO, it usually covers all the options in the branch...

Comment: There is a settings to do that. [Article](https://m.windowscentral.com/how-limit-windows-update-bandwidth-windows-10-fall-creators-update)

Comment: There isn’t a maximum upload percentage group policy for whatever reason

Comment: OK, when anyone finds out the option exists finaly, please let us know, thank you. We are suffering badly since Windows 10 in terms of connectivity overload/inusability...